# How would you set this up in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I recently got hired in a sales position and would like to make sure im getting paid for what I have sold.

I have a worksheet with 3 columns where I keep track of what I have sold, 1 column shows order number, 2nd column shows services I have sold and the other shows the amount I should be paid for services sold. In worksheet 2 my employer shows me there record of what I have sold and what they are paying out for each service. There worksheet is setup pretty much the same way. 3 columns showing order #, services sold and what they are paying for each service.

I would like to match my worksheet to theirs and make sure the amounts match.  If they don't match What can it highlight the cell or something that would indicate which orders don't have matching payout amounts, would be nice. How can I set this up what's the best formula to use and how do I set it up? MATCH or VLOOKUP or??

Comment: Please update the question title to match the contents.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).